# !$variable = $variable inside if

Tags: php, if-statement

I was gnawing on the basics of PHP socket servers and client [here](http://php.net/manual/en/sockets.examples.php).

Then I stumbled upon these lines (excerpt from the above links first example, happens inside `while`):

```
if (false === ($buf = socket_read($msgsock, 2048, PHP_NORMAL_READ))) {
    echo "socket_read() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($msgsock)) . "\n";
    break 2;
}

if (!$buf = trim($buf)) {
    continue;
}
```

I'm okay with the reading part, and closing connection in case there was an error reading.

But that next `if` is driving me nuts.
Firstly, I'm confused about how one may and would need to assign a value to boolean.
Secondly, I have trouble understanding the whole expression altogether.

Could someone please explain what happens inside that if, and how it applies to the server context?

P.S. Please excuse me if the question isn't properly asked. I'm just too confused about what happens there and have no idea what specifically to ask for.

Comment: +1 as i thought of it NOW! so i posted what i tried!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With this statement, there's no assignment to a boolean. We're comparing the type of `false` and the value of `false` (true false, not merely 0). You can read about that [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

```
if (false === ($buf = socket_read($msgsock, 2048, PHP_NORMAL_READ)))
```

Then

```
if (!$buf = trim($buf)) {
    continue;
}
```

This is the same as

```
$buf = trim($buf);
if ($buf == false) {
  continue;
}
```

So, to explain the original:

```
// The assignment happens first and then we're checking the boolean value
if (!$buf = trim($buf))
```

Comment: Would there be the same result if the expression was inside brackets `!($buf = trim($buf))`?

Comment: @psycketom yes, that would be the same

Comment: You can take a look at the precedence concepts to understand it better: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Answer (score 1):

Here's the explanation of the code.

```
false === ($buf = socket_read($msgsock, 2048, PHP_NORMAL_READ))
```

First, `socket_read` is called, and the result is stored in `$buf`. Then `$buf` is compared with `false` to see whether or not it is a `bool` and its value is `false`. (`===` means same type and equality at the same time)

```
if (!$buf = trim($buf)) {
    continue;
}
```

In this part of the code, first `$buf` is trimmed and the result is stored in `$buf`. Then it's checked whether or not the `$buf` is `false`. If it is false, `continue` takes action.

Answer (score 0):

The expression is splitable.

- `$buf = trim($foo)`
- `$check = !$buf`
- `if ($check) { something(); }`

first you get the variable, then check wether it evaluates to false (might be `false`, might be `null` might be `0`), and lastly oyu do the switch based on that information.

Answer (score 0):

### if you are seeking basics have a journey!

try this code

```
<?php
    $buf="0 ";// (note the spaces)
    //next try changing $buf="1 "; (note the spaces for trim)

    echo $buf ."<----Non trimmed buf<br>" ;
    $buf= trim($buf);
    echo $buf ."<----trimmed buf<br>" ;
    echo !$buf ."<----!buf<br>" ;

    if (!$buf = trim($buf))
       echo "Trimmed buf is false";
    else
       echo "Trimmed buf is True";
?>
```

**output**

```
0 <----Non trimmed buf
0<----trimmed buf
1<----!buf
Trimmed buf is false
```